# Not able to retrive list of document in mongodb

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb

```
{
    "question":"what is your color?",
    "choices":[{"option":"yello"},{"option":"blue"}],
    "creation-date":"2014-04-13",
    "expiry date":"2014-04-14"
}
```

In order to retrive list of polls

```
public List<Poll> getPolls()
{
  try {
       mongoClient=new MongoClient("NavDeep",27017);
       db=mongoClient.getDB("sms-voting");
       collection=db.getCollection("pollsCollection");
  }  catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
  List<Poll> polls = new ArrayList<Poll>();
  DBCursor cursor=collection.find();
  while(cursor.hasNext())
  {
       DBObject object = cursor.next();


      what should i write in order to retrieve List<Poll>????
        }   
    }
    mongoClient.close();
    return polls;
}
```

but i am getting null pointer exception near BasicDBList pollList=(BasicDBList)object.get("pollsCollection");
Can any body please Help me out.What should i actually write inside get()??

Thnks,
deepthi

Comment: "object" in your case here is the single "first" document from your collection. You got this when you iterated the cursor, so trying to call the "collection" from this is invalid. What are you actually trying to do? Return every document found from the collection as a List?

Comment: yes..I want to retrieve all the documents as a list

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be that you're doing cursor.next() twice in the lines above, pulling two records at a time.

What if you try:

```
polls.add(object)
```

instead of

```
polls.add(cursor.next())
```

Comment: Oh, sorry.There's no cursor.next() inside while loop.Thats my typo.Please ignore it.But i cannot do polls.add(cursor.next()) because cursor.next returns dbobject and polls is a list of java object called Poll.

Comment: Well, it might help if you fix typos in your code here so that we can try to diagnose it.  If you don't call cursor.next() inside the while loop, then how does object get assigned?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than iterating the cursor you appear to want the [**`.toArray()`**](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#toArray%28%29) method:

```
DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
List<DBObject> list = cursor.toArray();
```

Generally cursors are a good idea, and you probably should be building any array type results from within that loop. But this is a way to change the cursor.